# How to open .CS file from .CS file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am making a fake error spam and I want it to open my next .cs file but when I try the Process Start code it does not work.

Form 1 Code

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace Error_Message_Spam
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Error1();
        Error2();
        Error3();
        Error4();
        FakeRestart();

        RestartingWindow rw = new RestartingWindow();

    }

    public void Error1()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Deleting System32...", "Microsoft Windows",
        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
    }

    public void Error2()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Delete failed. Try again?", "Microsoft Windows",
        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
    }

    public void Error3()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Delete complete! Now time to restart your PC!!", "Microsoft Windows",
        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
    }

    public void Error4()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Restart?", "Microsoft Windows",
        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
    }

    public void FakeRestart()
    {   
        Task.Delay(5000);
        Exit();
    }

    public void Exit()
    {
        Environment.Exit(1);
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

RestartingWindow.cs code (the one I want to open)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Error_Message_Spam
{
public partial class RestartingWindow : Form
 {
    public RestartingWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
     }
 }
}
```

There is some stuff in the designer window. I want it to open in the FakeRestart() function in Form1.cs

Please Help!

(I am beginner level at C#)

Comment: Why have you tagged this as ASP.NET?

Comment: Also, `Task.Delay` won't actually cause an observable delay unless you await the task.

Comment: Can you also include the contents of your `Main` method?

Comment: My main method is the 1st one. Drew Noakes

Comment: To "open a .cs file" you would need the `File.Open` method of the `System.IO` namespace, but I guess that is not at all what you are looking for. Could you please clarify?

Comment: Hi Anders, I have the answer to the query. Thanks for being concerned. I also want to know how do I make a pause without the UI freezing like with the timer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After RestartingWindow rw = new RestartingWindow();
You have to do rw.Show();
The CS file is open, or rather, you have instantiated an instance of the RestartingWindow form, the problem is that you need to explicitly show it or it will remain invisible.

Comment: Thank you so much! How do I make it delay before it runs Exit()?

Comment: Not sure why that is happening. What does you main method look like. Does it look like this, Application.Run(new Form1()); its been a while since i worked with c#. Try doing rw.ShowDialog() instead of rw.Show(). I think that might do it.

Comment: Form1.cs and RestartingWindow.cs are my only cs files and Form1.cs is my main I think.

Comment: Try doing rw.ShowDialog() instead of rw.Show(). I think that might do it.